# genereting list from file python

Tags: python, list, file, random

I have a file that looks like this:**its exactly like this**

```
Pokemon     HP  Attack_Points   Type    Weakness
Bulbasaur   45     49     Grass Fire
Ivysaur     60     62     Grass Fire
Venusaur    80     82     Grass Fire
```

and I am trying to generate list from a random line and this is my code:

```
from random import randint

open_pokedex=open("pokedex.txt","r")
p1_p1=list()
pokemon_selection=(randint(1,40))
p1_p1.append(open_pokedex.readline()[pokemon_selection])
```

but this is not working anyone have any ideas?
output: it generetes 31 this time and shows p1_p1 as this = ['\t']

problem solved

but bcs of bad txt file it does this ['Charmander \t39\t52\tFire\tWater\n'] how to erase these tabs without messing with file itself

Comment: you probably want `readlines()` rather than `readline()`. You should show us what your code does/outputs at the moment so we have more info. Saying "it doesn't work" isn't useful as we need to know in what way it doesn't work.

Comment: yeah u re right let me change
edit: done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`linecache.getline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/linecache.html#linecache.getline). It does exactly what you want; getting line `lineno` from a file.

```
import linecache
from random import randint

pokemon_selection = randint(1, 40)
pokemon = linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection)
```

Comment: well i want to add them to list and changed your code to this p1_p1.linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection)
and it says AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'linecache'

Comment: @CiocomoTrombetta, Then, `p1_p1.append(pokemon)`
`

Comment: @CiocomoTrombetta, OR `p1_p1.append(linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection))`

Comment: yeah it worked thanks my bad forgot to add append there

Comment: @CiocomoTrombetta, Do you want to replace TAB character with space? `p1_p1.append(linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection).strip().replace('\t', ' '))`

Comment: @CiocomoTrombetta, `str.strip()` was used to remove spaces around the line (including newline)

Comment: @CiocomoTrombetta, BTW, instead of updating question more, please post another question if possible.

Comment: well im giving 3 random pokemons two players and i will show them which pokemons they got and this "/t"s looks bad and txt file is realy bad there are tab+blanks at somelines (we are not allowed to edit txt file)

Comment: i know str.strip but will it erease tabs to ?

Comment: @CiocomoTrombetta, `str.strip` remove leading, trailing spaces (including space, tabs, vertical tabs, newline). but not in the middle.

Comment: i want it to looks like this: [‘Bulbasaur’, 45, 49, ‘Grass’, ‘Fire’]

Comment: @CiocomoTrombetta, What you want is `str.split`: `p1_p1.append(linecache.getline("pokedex.txt", pokemon_selection).split())`

Comment: yeah thats do all the work i want to kiss you man :D but i think i need check list functions thank you very much